# How to redirect from this url using Lighttpd?

Tags: php, lighttpd

How can I redirect from `http://www.example.com/go/?http://www.example2.net` to `http://www.example2.net`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file `link.php` and set a global variable

```
<?php
$external = $_GET['go'];

// If a preloader header('Refresh: 4; url=' . $external);
header('Location: ' . $external);
?>
```

Then visit `http://www.example.com/link.php?go=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example2.net`

Answer (score 1):

I guess (from tags) you want to do this in lighttpd. In such case it would be:

```
url.redirect  = ( "^/go/\?(.*)$" => "$1" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just make a file go.php with the following url http://www.example.com/go.php?site=http://www.example2.net:

and the file go.php:

```
<?php
        header("Location: {$_GET['site']}");
        exit;
?>
```

Comment: You should do some input validation or you introduce possible HTTP response splitting, see http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/113.html

Comment: Agreed, but thought this would get him started :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have no URL rewriting and `/go` contains an index.php, you could do